# How is this a dangling pointer?

Tags: c, dangling-pointer

I was reading online about dangling pointers when I found the code on this link:

http://www.billioncodes.com/c/ques-and-ans/747-what-is-dangling-pointer-give-an-example-on-pointers-to-pointer-and-passing-by-address

I'll paste it here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int *j)
{
    (*j)++;
}
int main()
{
    int i = 20;
    int *p = &i;
    f(p);
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

How is this a dangling pointer, and which pointer is dangling? The code looks valid to me. It should print "i = 21" and return. I don't see any dangling pointer.

Comment: Hmm... did you execute the code to see if it actually does that?

Comment: There's no dangling pointer in this piece of code.

Comment: I suggest you never read anything at the billioncodes.com website again, there seems to be no sensible content there.

Comment: You probably ought to mistrust code that tries to make `in` a keyword in the language.  Could have happened, it didn't for another 30 years.

Comment: Ugh, I just looked at that website. It's total, utter crap, written in gibberish, suggesting bad practices and abusing terminology.

Comment: Please post the line the compiler is complaining about and the exact error message.

Comment: @1sand0s: The OP didn't say the compiler complained (and compilers don't always complain about dangling pointers, even when they exist).

Comment: So I was wondering where he got the idea a pointer was dangling.  I thought maybe his compiler complained. And it's not true that compilers won't warn about unused variables. lint does, obviously, but I haven't seen every C compiler on every platform, for all I know his compiler complained about something.  I don't see any dangling references there, but just in case his compiler balked, I wanted to know.

Comment: @1sand0s: I said compilers don't *always* complain about dangling pointers (or unused variables, but that's not the same thing). The web site (which apparently is really bad) mentioned dangling pointers, and incorrectly presented this code as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no dangling pointer in that program.

`p` is initialized to point to `i`. Both `p` and `i` have exactly the same lifetime; `p` ceases to exist at the same time that `i` does (on leaving the nearest enclosing block).

`j`, the `int*` parameter in the function `f`, points to `i` (it's initialized to the value of the argument `p`, which points to `i`). The lifetime of `j` is limited to the execution of the block in the function `f`; `i`'s starts after `i`'s lifetime begins and ends before `i`'s lifetime ends.

The program should print `i = 21`. No dangling pointers, no undefined behavior. (`int main()` should be `int main(void)`, but that's a minor point.)